# react inside loop with two different API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaoRC.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPge5.jpg

i have this to fetch two different API's.

***API #1*** Fetches the Name not organized by ranking
***API #2*** Fetches the ID of the name Organized by ranking, so i need to do a inside loop if the ID and Name Matches to get the Name of the player.

***Something like this i did on Async fuction***

```
    <script>
        getData();


        async function getData() {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3008/api/highscore/players')
            console.log(response);
            const data = await response.json();
            const req = await fetch('http://localhost:3008/api/players')
            console.log(req);
            const info = await req.json();
            length = data.players.length;
            console.log(data);
            var temp = "";
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < length; j++)  {
                    {


                        if (info.players[i].id == data.players[j].id) {

                            temp += "<tr>";
                            temp += "<td>" + data.players[j].position + "</td>";
                            temp += "<td>" + info.players[i].name + "</td>";
                            temp += "<td>" + data.players[j].score + "</td>";
                            temp += "</tr>";
                        }

                    }
                }
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = temp;
        }
```

***This is my React APP Code where i need it done :*** How can i go about it? any idea? any help will be deeply appreciate it!

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Ranking = () => {
  const [playerName, setPlayerName] = useState([]);
  const [playerRank, setPlayerRank] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    const playerAPI = 'http://localhost:3008/api/players';
    const playerRank = 'http://localhost:3008/api/highscore/players';

    const getINFOPlayer = axios.get(playerAPI)
    const getPlayerRank = axios.get(playerRank)
    axios.all([getINFOPlayer, getPlayerRank]).then(
      axios.spread((...allData) => {
        const allDataPlayer = allData[0].data.players
        const getINFOPlayerRank = allData[1].data.players

        setPlayerName(allDataPlayer)
        setPlayerRank(getINFOPlayerRank)
      })
    )
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
        <tbody>
          {playerName?.map((name) => {
            return (
              <tr key={name.name}>
                <td>{name.name}</td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>


    </table>
  )
}

export default Ranking
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is the rendered content [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlt3C.jpg)

What type of backend language you use? or you are using remote server? this can be done on the backend, but only if you have access to it.
Spring boot is amazing at this, with ORM you can Easly map tables using @ManyToOne or @OneToMany relation. I can do this for you if you want, please contact me.

if you just want to go with your code, or you are getting the response from a remote server, then fetch the responses, put the data in playerInf and rankInfo states, respectively. after use this code directly in return method:

// in your app add the following functions, replace the url and call them in useEffect hook or in the function of your choice.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
function App(props) {
    useEffect(()=> {
       // get the data from the website every 24 hours
       const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          playerInfoData();
          playerRankData();
       }, 86400000);
       return ()=> {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        };
    },[]);

    const playerInfoData = () => {
            fetch(`resources/jsons/player.json`,//replace your url here
                {   
                headers : { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
                
            }).then(res => res.json()).then(
                data => {
                    setPlayerInfo(data);
                    setReady(true);
                    
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            
        }
        const playerRankData = () => {
            fetch(`resources/jsons/rank.json`,
                {   
                headers : { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
                
            }).then(res => res.json()).then(
                data => {
                    setRankInfo(data);
                    setReady(true);
                    
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    // ready is used to tell react to not render unless data is ready
    return (
    {ready && playerInfo.map(player => {
                
                    return (
                          <tr key={player.name}>
                            <td>{ready && rankInfo.map(rank => {
                                if(player.id === rank.id){
                                    return rank.value;
                                }
                            })
                            }</td>
                            <td>{player.name}</td>
                            <td>{player.points}</td>
                          </tr>
                        )
                      })
                  }
            )

}
```

again, this is not good practice, always do your logic in backend and customize the response. I can help you with that, contact me if you want to know more.

Comment: please add me on discord so we can share more information: yandr1#1755

Comment: i use this code and ready is undefined, but the code looks good, im using react app as backend with components on jsx

Comment: please create a const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);  and update it to true after the data is loaded

Comment: just did,   Line 30:1:   Nested block is redundant                                                          no-lone-blocks
  Line 34:43:  Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function this is what i get in return on visual studio

Comment: lol no worries, are you getting the data from json file?

Comment: if so I will post anothe answer using fetch api, hope it will work for you.

Comment: im getting the data from a .jsx file, i have other .JS files that i get data from for the welcome page, i posted some pictures so you see better.

Comment: ok, try to use the two functions I just add. change the url to your jsx file....

Comment: okay, im going to try it, thank you really much for your help, the only problem i see with this last code is that the data i get is from a website that is updated every 24 hours, so if i download the information to a json file it wont be the same. and im really sorry i'm still pretty new to this coding world myself thank you so much for your help

Comment: no problem, you are welcome. code is the same, just change the URL to the website URL. and you can use an Interval to update the data every 24 hours. I will add the code for you in the post.

Comment: thanks for that code brother, im going to work it out! really appreciate it much love